# Is a transaction(like token transfer) could fail after being sent? if so, how can I get information about it?

Tags: transactions, blocks

In EOSIO, we know that a transaction can be packed in block very fast, and we can also treat it as irreversible after "lastirreversibleblock >= block_num".

1. Whether a transaction could fail after being included in block, if so, how do I know about it?
2. and Whether a transaction could fail before being included in a block?

---

many thanks..

Answer (score 1):

> Whether a transaction could fail after being included in block, if so, how do I know about it?

Yes, once the transaction is in a block it is not executed anymore and, hence, can't fail.

> Whether a transaction could fail before being included in a block?

Yes, the response of the transaction call will contain the error.

Comment: What happens if a transaction is included in a block, but that block is then lost due to a fork and re-organization?  How can I detect the loss/failure of the transaction?

Comment: If you want to synchronize the state of the chain you should probably be a node. You app probably shouldn't rely on the state changes but on the state itself. Could you clarify your use case?

Comment: @friedger thanks.
so a transaction can't fail after being included in a block, and once a transaction being sent, I can immediately know it failed or not through response, right? 
Another question, is a transaction sent successful but never being included in a block?